# temperature probes, voltage probes, etc. .dll

Tags: python, windows

I am working on a program in python to monitor temperature of cpu and various other things including motherboard voltages.

I have tried using wmi, and acpi to read the probes, and have had no luck. this has been discussed here: http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=26726

I am now trying to read from a dll with ctypes module and am wondering if anyone knows what .dll(s) are used to get the readings for things like Win32_TemperatureProbe.  if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The temperature probe and others is hardware and bios dependant.  Try looking at the bios screen, if the CPU temp is displayed there wmi will give it to you, else try upgrading bios or try a new motherboard

Honestly if in this day and age your server is not recording temperature at bios your motherboard is too cheap to be a server

Comment: ok i looked in the bios, the cpu temp works.  but under wmi it still does not work.  i upgraded the bios also. nothing. is there any reason why bios hardware monitoring works but wmi does not?

Comment: is there a way to access bios information directly from python?  Thanks!